# Bass Class using VB

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

There are many pages on the net which show how to remove a meta tag from code behind but none of them work in my situation

I am using a custom Base Class (no need to post code as none of it is relevent to this question) which is inherited by an asp.net page. The aspx page uses a master page

The multiple pages all over the Internet assume you are using code behind for a tag on that page rather than being set via a Base Page

Sure I can add this code in the master page but then I have to use the MasterType VirtualPath directive but even having the ID's set and the runat server in the html markup doesn't help. Having them in the Base Class makes it so no directive etc has to be used.

If I add the meta tag description in the page markup it shows and then if I use the code to add a new HtmlMeta using Header.Controls.Add(my tag reference here) I then have 2 tags names description for example, which is no good. I wish to be able to check and remove the first one but all the code out there doesn't work from a Base Class.

For all those people who ask for the pointless code, do this:

Open Visual Studio
New VB.NET Web App or Website
Add App_Code folder
Add new Class to the App_Code folder
Add a master page
Add a new page using the above master page and change the inherits ... Page to whatever you called the class in the App_Code folder

---

I don't want this

Add a MetaTag description to the page, id and runat server which means you can control it from the code behind.

because I wish for this to be removed and replaced by a description meta in the Base Class, if it exists or just written if it doesn't

---

Now you can use the code in any of the links below but instead of using it in the page code behind, add it to the base class in the App_Code folder

Call the code from the code behind of the page

http://forums.asp.net/t/1724349.aspx?How+to+remove+meta+tag+from+header+progrmmatically+
http://forums.asp.net/t/1223617.aspx
http://forums.asp.net/t/1518853.aspx

The easiert way to describe it:

If the Meta Tage exists, remove it and replace it or change the content of the existing one

Why do I want this funtionality in the base class? You do it once and can call the code from any page it's inherited from rather than statically adding it to 100+ pages.

This is the closest I've found so far but the properties are always empty (null):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17368/Using-Meta-Tags-with-Master-Pages-in-ASP-NET

I am only interested in any solution using the Base Class and not the same code over & over again in the code behind of every page or using the MasterType Virtual path way (code in the master page) like this:

[Overwrite Meta Tags from Master Page with Content Page meta tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923300/overwrite-meta-tags-from-master-page-with-content-page-meta-tags)

Comment: Ok the custom base class code may not be relevant, but some example code of what is on the aspx and what with and how you would like to replace it would help immensely to understand what you are asking.

Comment: I resolved it. It seems the asp.net forum post used Me.FindControl rather than Me.Header.FindControl and swapping that out with the other code works fine so issue closed

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the idea in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17368/Using-Meta-Tags-with-Master-Pages-in-ASP-NET which works perfectly for me